# How Object objects return Strings? (Java)

Tags: java

If `Object` is the mother of all classes in the hierarchy, how can he implement a method returning an object of a child class (e.g `toString` returns a `String` object)?

Comment: +1 "Object is the mother of all classes" - lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an interesting point: The [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class knows about one of its subclasses, namely [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) (in particular, to declare and implement the [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method).

Part of the java language specification is that all classes are implicitly subclasses of Object. Although technically it is "poor design" for a class to refer to one of its subclasses, I think it's an "edge case" and not something to be worried about.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a problem as long as the child class exists. For example, the following is valid:

**A.java:**

```
public class A {
    B b;
}
```

**B.java:**

```
public class B extends A {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

because there is a default implementation of `toString` on `Object` that makes sure a `String` instance is returned.  Since every class is an instance of an `Object` you always get that default implementation for free, although you can and should implement `toString` on subclasses.

There is nothing preventing methods in any class returning instances of another class.  You can always do

`return new SomethingElse()`

where `SomethingElse` is another class.